# Error while integrating Three20 to an iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, three20

I am tring to integrate Three20 to my project. I followed the same instructions given in this page

[Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20). But I am getting CANNOT FIND #import "Three20/Three20.h" issue.

Header Search path under Project info > Build i have set as ../three20/Build/Products/three20

Please suggest me what can be the problem in my header search path setting?

Thanks
Deepika

Comment: do `three20/` and your project share the same parent folder?

Comment: Would it be normal etiquette for Anurag to copy his comment to an answer and for Deepika to set it as answered?  That way other people will know the question has already been answered *and* Deepika's answer rate will improve from 17%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Create your project (for example: **SampleApp**)
2 - Copy **three20** folder into **SampleApp** folder
3 - Your directory structure will be as followed
|
|
|SampleApp
|---three20
|---SampleApp.xcodeproj
|---*other files and folder*

4 - In the command line, run this script at the **SampleApp** directory

**python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p ./SampleApp.xcodeproj Three20**

5 - DONE

Answer (score 1):

I was pulling my hair out as well since adding three20 correctly to your new iOS4 with really basic instructions listed here: http://github.com/facebook/three20 did not work as well.

Issue: Can compile newly three20 to your iOS project and got this error: Can't find #import "Three20/Three20.h".

Here is the best solution for those have the same issue: 
1) Add your three20 to your iphone project path like this:  
     [yourProjectPath]/[iOSProjectName]/three20/.. 
2) cd three20 dir 
3) run: 
python src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p [yourProjectPath]/[iOSProjectName]/[iOSProjectName].xcodeproj Three20 -c Debug -c Release  
4) go to XCode and do a build now.

Thanks to jverkoey for adding this in ...man  
u save us a lot of headache if u ever read this :- ) kudos bud! :- )  
http://github.com/facebook/three20/commit/0814b1c149cbe987557c88a271f999c3f9f3ae64 
 
Please vote this answers if it help u. Thanks :-)